# In iOS 6, how exactly does one add a "Facebook Like" button?

Tags: facebook-like, ios6

I'm looking for the simplest implementation of this, hopefully avoid a web page interface.

If this is possible, could someone please post code or a link to example code for this?

Cheers
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Similar post : [iOS 6 - Facebook 'Like' Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269466/ios-6-facebook-like-button)

The Ray Wenderlich post is a pretty straight forward way but its not the prettiest as it just uses a webview to load a hacky webpage. 
[Ray Wenderlich Approach](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app)

Using the open graph api is more professional but its also more complex. 
[Open Graph Approach](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes/)