# iOS 6 - Facebook 'Like' Button

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios6, facebook-like

I have just implemented Facebook SDK 3.1.1 into my app with the intention of being able to share a picture, as well as 'Like' our product page from within the app. I can't seem to find a simple explanation or tutorial on how to code a button to automatically 'Like' a particular Facebook page. Can this only be done within a UIWebView? Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the link below which may help you in your work:

[RayWenderlich: How To Post to a User’s Wall, Upload Photos, and Add a Like Button from your iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. The only way to like a Facebook page from within the iOS app, is to load up a `UIWebView` that navigates to the page, and then the user can like it.

Answer (score 0):

Through Vishal's answer, I came to this link which can construct an iFrame 'Like' button which can be added in a UIWebView.

[Construct Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the FBlike button using the following code but it need to download latest sdk and it is the beta version :(

Here is the code:

```
[FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesLikeButton];
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility:NO];
FBLikeControl *like = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];
like.objectID = @"http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/photo1/";
like.likeControlHorizontalAlignment=FBLikeControlHorizontalAlignmentRight;
like.likeControlStyle=FBLikeControlStyleBoxCount;
[self.view addSubview like];
```